# searching for a ad network sdk for wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

i'm searching for a ad network for wp7, i tryed a lot and here are my oppinions:

1. admob: nearly 0% fillrate
2. smaato: ugly implementation of the ad SDK (ads dont display right)
3. mobfox: like admob no fill rate
4. millenniummedia: sdk dont work, the sample work but my app with the exact code doesn't
5. adduplex: the side is realy bad, the overview is terrible and its only 80% ads that brings money

so which alternatives do i have?
i'm a non us developer, so the official wp7 sdk is not the right thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a fairly full list, have you considered trying out Ad Rotator?

I understand it has options to allow you to change proportions of ad network per country.

[Ad Rotator info](http://www.wpcentral.com/wp7-ad-rotator-rotates-your-ads) here and [Ad Rotator source / release](http://wp7adrotator.codeplex.com/) here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using WP7 Ad Rotator (found on codeplex) for my XNA game Alien Escape. You can then adjust your ad rotation based on which ads have higher eCPM. It works amazingly well.